# Defining Variables or constant in XMLwriter PHP

Tags: php, xmlwriter

i am new in PHP. Using xmlwriter to produce an xml file. I have below code.

```
$xml = new XMLWriter(); 
$xml->openURI('test.xml');

$xml->setIndent(true);
$mmmid = '1981';


$xml->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->text('<raml xmlns="raml21.xsd" version="2.1">');
$xml->text('    <cmData scope="all" type="plan">'); 
$xml->text('        <header>');

$xml->text('            <log dateTime="2012-11-05T12:27:50+02:00" appInfo="Manager" user="WebUI" appVersion="4.5133.90" action="created"/>');

$xml->text('        </header>');    

$xml->text('                    <managedObject class="MRBTS" distName="IDENTITY-'$mmmid'" operation="create" version="1803">');
$xml->text('                    <p name="btsName">B1123</p>');
$xml->text('                </managedObject>');
```

I want to define the mmmid in the output of xml file, so it will be appeared in the output distName="IDENTITY-1981"

How can i define variable mmmid in the code and expected printed in output of the text above?

Thank you a lot,
Br,FM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When concatenating a variable with strings in PHP there are several ways of doing it.

#### Use double quotes `"` as surrounding delimiters

When using double quotes `"` in PHP you can use variables inside the string as usual

```php
$foo = 4;
echo "Hello $foo";
```

**Output**:

```
Hello 4
```

This would give the following solution for your problem:

```php
# Note that you need to escape the original double quotes with a backslash
$xml->text("<managedObject distName=\"IDENTITY-$mmmid\" operation=\"create\" version=\"1803\">');
```

#### Concatenate with a dot `.`

Another way of binding a variable with text is by using a dot `.` between the variable and string (this also works with only strings or only variables as well). For this method you can use either single `'` or double quotes `"`.

```php
$foo = 4;
echo 'Hello ' . $foo;
```

**Output**

```
Hello 4
```

And with this method it would give you this

```php
$xml->text('<managedObject distName="IDENTITY-' . $mmmid . '" operation="create" version="1803">');
```

Comment: that works.... the dot works fine... the backslash tried maybe my mistake.. i ll try again...

Comment: Great to hear @FernandoManik, the reason you need to escape the quotes with `\"` in the double quotes `"` solution is because you would escape the delimiter otherwise. However, in your case it would likely be easier to use the dot-version instead. If you feel you've received help enough to solve your problem, feel free to mark the answer that helped you the most, as an accepted answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

That would be it:

```
$xml->text('                    <managedObject class="MRBTS" distName="IDENTITY-' . $mmmid . '" operation="create" version="1803">');
```

You concatinate strings in PHP via the `.` operator, see the [PHP manual](https://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) on strings